# Custom Taxonomy not displaying all post

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have created 15 post and assigned to the custom taxonomy. It is not displaying all the 15 post. It shows only 10 post.

Please guide me. Thanks

```
wp_reset_query();
$args = array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'parent_login_gallery',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => array($_REQUEST['term_id']),
            'operator' => 'IN',
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
        ),
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

```
wp_reset_query();
            $args = array(
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'parent_login_gallery',
                        'field'    => 'term_id',
                        'terms'    => array($_REQUEST['term_id']),
                        'operator' => 'IN',
                        'public' => true,
                        'has_archive' => true,
                    ),
                )
            );
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following parameter to your query:

```
'posts_per_page' => 15
```

If that does not work check the setting at settings > reading and set the number of posts there.